# Split list python list of number into multiple lists

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have the following python list:

```
x = ["56843", "84631", "13831"]
```

And I want to get the following list:

```
x = [ ["5","6","8","4","3"] , ["8","4","6","3","1"] ]
```

How can I achieve this?

I have tried with split, but I need a separator that I don't know which is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just this:

```
x = [list(y) for y in x]
```

`list(y)` which `y` is a string will convert the string into a list of characters.

Answer (score 0):

```py
x = [[ch for ch in s] for s in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ["56843","84631","13831"]

c = []

for i in x:
    c.append(list(i))

print(c)
```